# AWS EKS - Failure creating load balancer controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubectl, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am trying to create an application load balancer controller on my EKS cluster by following
[this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html)

When I run these steps (after making the necessary changes to the downloaded yaml file)

```
curl -o v2_1_2_full.yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1.2/docs/install/v2_1_2_full.yaml
kubectl apply -f v2_1_2_full.yaml
```

I get this output

```
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/targetgroupbindings.elbv2.k8s.aws configured
mutatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/aws-load-balancer-webhook configured
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aws-load-balancer-controller-leader-election-role unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aws-load-balancer-controller-role configured
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aws-load-balancer-controller-leader-election-rolebinding unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aws-load-balancer-controller-rolebinding unchanged
service/aws-load-balancer-webhook-service unchanged
deployment.apps/aws-load-balancer-controller unchanged
validatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/aws-load-balancer-webhook configured
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "v2_1_2_full.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": Post https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s: no endpoints available for service "cert-manager-webhook"
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "v2_1_2_full.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": Post https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s: no endpoints available for service "cert-manager-webhook"
```

The load balancer controller doesnt appear to start up because of this and never gets to the ready state

Has anyone any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the taints on my nodegroup prevented the cert-manager pods from starting on any node.

These commands helped debug and led me to a fix for this issue:

```
kubectl get po -n cert-manager
kubectl describe po <pod id> -n cert-manager
```

My solution was to create another nodeGroup with no taints specified. This allowed the cert-manager to run.